# npm build run package (react) terminal command

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-build

How to update "build" folder of a project after changes or updates?

I tried npm update but can't update the build folder while I made changes of my project

Comment: you can try to use `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `npm run build` command for building it again. It overrides the previous one.